# Using ora:view with XMLTable to Query a Relational Table as XML

Tags: xquery, xmltype

I have an Oracle relational table called DOCTYPES with columns ID, DOCTYPE, SUBTYPE.

When I run the following statement in Oracle SQL Developer

```
SELECT * FROM XMLTable('for $i in ora:view("LAZ", "DOCTYPES")/ROW
                        return $i/SUBTYPE')
```

I get back the results between  tags as expected. But when I run the following statement I get an error:

```
SELECT * FROM XMLTable('for $i in ora:view("LAZ", "DOCTYPES")/ROW
                        return <SUBTYPE="{$i/SUBTYPE}"/>')
```

LPX-00801: XQuery syntax error at '='. I don't understand why the second statement doesn't work.

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: I'm using the examples from http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb_xquery.htm as reference. I believe it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know what Oracle makes of XQuery, but the statement between the apostrophes clearly has an XQuery syntax error at '=', as IMO was correctly diagnosed.

This is because you are opening a direct element constructor, but an equals sign incorrectly follows the tag name. An equals sign is used inside of a direct element constructor to separate attribute names from attribute values. So the following might work:

```
SELECT * FROM XMLTable('for $i in ora:view("LAZ", "DOCTYPES")/ROW
                        return <SUBTYPE name="{$i/SUBTYPE}"/>')
```

For the specification, please refer to [3.7.1 Direct Element Constructors](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#id-element-constructor) in the [XQuery recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/).

Answer (score -1):

Syntax was wrong.

```
SELECT * FROM XMLTable('for $i in ora:view("LAZ", "DOCTYPES")/ROW
                    return <SUBTYPE="{data($i/SUBTYPE)}"/>')
```

Comment: It would be surprising if this is any better than the original, as far as the syntax error at '=' is concerned.

Comment: Correct, I missed the attribute there.